# Install Gitlab on Cent

Tags: git, gitlab, centos7, redmine, httpd.conf

I have a Centos 7 web server where Git+Gitolite+GitWeb and Redmine already run successfully on apache (httpd). 
Currently, I can access to GitWeb and redmine simply from a URL on my webpage (http://localhost/gitweb for gitweb and http://localhost/redmine for redmine), as well as to shared folders.

I tried to install Gitlab-ee in order to improve the management of my Git repos from webpage without removing everything, just adding a new path to mu URL (http://localhost/gitlab).
Given that Gitlab works on nginx, I can access to Gitlab opnly stopping my httpd service.
I tried to modify the gitlab configuration in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, adding this modification

```
external_url 'http://localhost/gitlab'
web_server['external_users'] = ['apache']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

then I added the gitlab group to the gitlab-www group:

```
usermod apache --append --groups gitlab-www
```

and I edited my as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    #RailsEnv production
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /pm /var/www/redmine/public

    <Location /pm>  
        #PassengerUser sw_srv
        PassengerBaseURI /pm
            PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine
            #PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Location>

   <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

    #Alias /git /var/www/git
    <Directory /var/www/git>
       Options       None
       AllowOverride none
       Order         allow,deny
       Allow         from all
    </Directory>

    SuexecUserGroup git git
    ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
    ScriptAlias /gitmob/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh

    <Location /git>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        Require valid-user
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/git.passwd
    </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location /gitlab>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all

      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/gitlab/
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

    # needed for downloading attachments
    DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined env=!dontlog

</VirtualHost>
```

obviously restarting apache, it doesn't work.

please can anyone help me?

Comment: If its working on ngnix already successfully, then you can make ngnix listen on different port, and have apache reverse-proxy it via that url...

Comment: I tried to do it. Before editing the nginx lister port, I would like to enable the apache reverse-proxy, restoring the other pages. But probably my apache configuration is wrong

Comment: I see that you are using proxy already, you must first change ngnix and ensure its working on that port, then setup apache to proxypass on it.